# Grails: legacy database: foreign key that has not the same type in each mapped table

Tags: grails, mapping, grails-orm

So I have a grails model looking like this:

```
class Tree {
    Long id;
    String name;
    static hasMany = [branches: Branch
}

class Branch {
    Long id;
    String name;
    static belongsTo = [tree: Tree]
}
```

The issue is that in DB, the Tree id is a number, while the tree_id in the Branch table is a varchar. 
The db model is a de facto foreign key that is not enforced at all as a constraint.

Gorm generate a query that is not handled by my database: it tries to bing a numerical value where text is expected:
 ERROR util.JDBCExceptionReporter  - ORA-01722: invalid number

How can I tell GORM to convert the value before binding the parameter ?

I looked in the [join table config](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) but I did not find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `sqlType` in [`column`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/column.html) definition in mappings?

```
class Branch {
    Long id
    String name
    static belongsTo = [tree: Tree]

    static mapping = {
        tree column: 'TREE_ID', sqlType: "char"
    }
}
```

Unable to test right now, but do let me know.